# best database for reading millions of records on secondary index

Tags: aerospike

currently i am using aerospike database for storing near about 27 million records on EBS and when i scan this data on secondary index, throughput is very low. please somebody suggest what are the possible alternatives. thanks in advance.

Comment: Performance on EBS will be slow and IOPS will limit the read tps. Read tps will be same as IOPS on EBS only store. Use bcache or data-in-memory true

Comment: Make sure kernel is 3.18+ https://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2015/sites/default/files/slides/all_your_iops_are_belong_to_usPLMCE2015.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the comment as an answer..

Performance on EBS will be slow and IOPS will limit the read tps. Read tps will be same as IOPS on EBS only store. Use bcache or data-in-memory true.

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/ssd/bcache/